# How do I reset a GFCI outlet when the buttons don't respond?

Tags: electrical, gfci

Our electric pole attached to our house was destroyed and now the pole is fixed and I have electricity in most of my house. Unfortunately, this 1 outlet has both the red and black reset buttons pushed in and won't work.

How can I fix this so that this outlet will work?

Comment: Replacement might be the best.  Adding a good picture of the outlet will help others tell what it is, but probably just a GFCI outlet.  Power pole destroyed and that is the only problem in the house, lucky.

Comment: So, just replacing the whole outlet will probably work? Yeah just tore our pole out of the ground and ripped all the wires from the pole. Didn’t have electricity for a week and half right at Christmas time also.

Answer (score 11):

What you are referring to is most likely a Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter, or GFCI, combined with a receptacle. A GFCI protects against injury and death due to current going from the receptacle to people, especially in wet areas. It has been required for decades in kitchens and bathrooms and more recently in other areas (laundry room, garage, outside, etc.).

A GFCI is designed to not reset if:

- It detects damage to itself - i.e., an automatic self-test fails. This is a standard function of newer models.
- It detects a ground fault within the attached receptacle.
- It detects a ground fault in any receptacle or device attached to the "Load" terminals.

When an electric pole is destroyed (e.g., lightning strike or truck knocks it down), there can be a **HUGE** surge which will have unknown effects on nearby attached equipment, possibly including everything in your house. A GFCI can be affected either directly (because it has sensitive electronic components) or indirectly (a device protected by the GFCI could get overloaded in a way that causes a permanent ground-fault, preventing the GFCI from resetting). In addition, a breaker or another device on the circuit *before* the GFCI/breaker could be damaged. When a pole is destroyed, pretty much anything can happen.

The starting point is to check the circuit breaker. If there are other receptacles or lights on the same circuit breaker that are working the breaker is OK and the problem is likely at or after the GFCI/receptacle. On the other hand, if *nothing* on the circuit works then the problem may be at the breaker. Unfortunately, sometimes it is hard to tell as often a GFCI/receptacle is used to protect all receptacles on a circuit - e.g., for a required kitchen countertop receptacle circuit.

If that doesn't help narrow down the problem then the next step is to isolate the GFCI/receptacle:

- Turn off the breaker
- Open up the box with the GFCI/receptacle
- Use a non-contact voltage tester (NCVT) to make sure there is no power in the box (i.e., that the breaker is truly off)
- If there are wires on the "Load" terminals then disconnect them and then turn the breaker back on and try the GFCI reset again
- If there are no wires on the "Load" terminals or if disconnecting them doesn't help, I would try a new GFCI/receptacle as it may be damaged (new cost ~ $15 - $20)

If that doesn't get you anywhere, post pictures of what you found (take pictures *before* disconnecting any wires) and pictures of your breaker panel and upload them for more help.

Comment: Does someone not like you?

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try that. I don’t think it was a question of someone not liking me. I live at a dead end street and they came down it anyway and then turned around in our drive way and there camper trailer took out our lines and pole and then drove off.

Comment: There was one at the time, maybe it was a mistake and they changed it.

Comment: Note that most GFCIs will not reset unless they are being powered, and may ship in "safe" mode -- so you need to hook up, turn the breaker on, and then push the reset button and hope to hear and feel a click as it powers up.

Comment: If you pull the CFCI outlet out you can use a voltmeter to check if the breaker is sending power.

Comment: @Joshua As long as you're careful. Safest is: turn off breaker, pull out GFCI/receptacle and position it so that all bare wires (except ground), screws, etc. are safely away from the box, turn on breaker, check voltage.